# Is there a way to include a jar in a Jenkins Pipeline folder-level shared library?

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, classpath, jenkins-pipeline

The Jenkins Pipeline shared docs include this:

> The src directory should look like standard Java source directory structure. This directory is added to the classpath when executing Pipelines.

So that statement seems inaccurate when a jar (or a class file) is included in the directory structure.

I stood up an instance of the latest version of Jenkins Pipeline and received a class loading error when I tried to import a class from an implicitly loaded folder-level shared library in my Jenkinsfile.

So is there a way to include a jar in a pipeline's classpath so that the jar's classes are available to the pipeline?




PS I don't want to add a jar to the lib/ext dir of the JDK/JRE Jenkins is using, a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707846/676887.