# Is there some way to pull in Jenkins plugins from a shared pipeline library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

Jenkins publishes plugins which contains primarily, or only, additional pipeline steps.

For example, [pipeline-utility-steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/) would be nice to have, because it has the `tar` task.

But getting additional plugins installed in the Jenkins instance comes with some difficulty - only one or two devs have access to do so, and they're reluctant to add more plugins, because more plugins installed means more work overall - they have to be tested for cross-compatibility, kept up to date, tracked for vulnerabilities, etc.

Jenkins lets us maintain our own shared pipeline libraries, which we are already using as a place to put all our own *custom* steps.

**Is there some way we can make use of the shared pipeline library feature, to also gain access to existing Jenkins plugins without installing them in Jenkins?**

For example, can we directly import a Jenkins plugin into a pipeline somehow to use its steps? 
Or can we do something in our shared pipeline library to make it also pull in additional vars from some other Jenkins plugin?

Similar questions:

- [Is there a way to include a jar in a Jenkins Pipeline folder-level shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454743/) asks about one specific way this might be possible

Comment: "For example, can we directly import a Jenkins plugin into a pipeline somehow to use its steps?" No: the plugin must be installed before it can be imported UNLESS you retrieve it within the library, which is basically equivalent to installing it during every execution, but within the code. If you want the functionality without the installation, then you could always fork the code, but then you also become responsible for maintaining that.

Comment: Additionally I would expect `pipeline-utility-steps` to be installed in every Jenkins installation using pipeline without a second thought, but I understand it is not a true example of the plugins your are describing.